# How do I prevent crashing from invalid user input?

Tags: c#

I have encountered a problem where my program crashes due to the input of the user not  following the variable data type. What I am asking the user to do is register some data for a movie. When we reach the year of release for the movie, it crashes, should the user input not follow the integer data type.

What I then also was trying to do is to make sure the value of int release is a number between 1000 and 2050.

What I want to have happen:
The user is forced to enter a value between 1000 and 2050. Should a different value be entered, he is asked to try again.

The code I believe should be relevant:

```
public static void RegisterMovie()
    {
        Console.Write("Ange titel: ");
        string title = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Ange genre: ");
        string genre = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Ange release: ");
        int release = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.Write("Ange actor: ");
        string actor = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Ange director: ");
        string director = Console.ReadLine();

        Movie m = CreateMovie(title, genre, release, actor, director);
        AddMovie(m);
    }
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Use a while loop and int.TryParse(). That should get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
bool ok = false;
int release;
while (!ok)
 {
   Console.Write("Ange release: ");
   ok = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out release);
   ok = ok && (release >= 1000) && (release <= 2050);
 }
```

Comment: Actually, I'd use a do..while loop instead, here. `do { ... } while (!ok);` just feels more natural for me for something that should always execute at least once.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Int32.TryParse()` and handle the case when it's not an integer.  The return value indicates whether the operation succeeded.
For more information see
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use TryParse instead.

```
Console.Write("Ange release: ");
int release;
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out release))
{
    Console.Write("Ange release: ");
}
```